# Is omitting subject-auxiliary verb combination a formal and grammatical way of writing?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, ellipsis, formality

> The left hand side of the equation is equal to the right hand side of it. Hence, proved.

Wouldn't it be grammatically like this-

> The left hand side of the equation is equal to the right hand side of it. Hence, **it is** proved.

I hope the auxiliary verb **are** is used correctly in the given below another example.

> The ongoing call or data session are not disconnected, hence no financial loss.
>
> The ongoing call or data session are not disconnected, hence **there is** no financial loss.

Comment: It's definitely not "grammatical". Whether it's *idiomatic* or not is more a  matter of opinion. In *my* opinion you should avoid things like this - it's really just throwing a couple of meaningful words out and leaving it to the audience to figure out how they combine to actually *mean* something.

Comment: I think your *hence no financial loss* is structurally akin to the "minimalist" (read: *missing*) modern syntax of, for example, [*I'm late **because** YouTube*](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2013/11/english-has-a-new-preposition-because-internet/281601/). Learners will often say things like this because they don't know any better - but the fact that some *native* speakers now do it deliberately isn't exactly a good reason for copying them.

Comment: Is your question specifically about sentences using the adverb "hence" Please clarify.  Also "is" in your examples is the main verb of the clause, not an auxillary, again, please edit to correct this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word **hence** is used to say to the listener, "and thus, *what we are seeking to demonstrate* has been demonstrated". It is already curt.

"Hence, there is no financial loss" and "hence it is proved" would be grammatical and normal. The ellipsis (hence, proved; hence no financial loss) would sound a little strange in a formal context if there were no clear and compelling reason for such brevity.

Such brevity is more commonly associated with a teacher in front of a blackboard going over the logical steps once again, say, or with a businessperson going through a list of items and not wanting to repeat the same formulaic words with each item visited.

Comment: Does the term ellipsis apply even when the subject part is omitted along with the verb?

Comment: @Anubhav Singh: I believe I may not understand your question. What do you mean by "term" and what do you mean by "apply"?  Are you intimating that it is possible to analyze the construction differently?

Comment: Note that as with all parallel structures, repeated elements are liable to disappear without any laziness. "She is a genius and hence highly promotable" is neither informal nor formal. Are you thinking of this kind of thing, @AnubhavSingh?…

Comment: Hence my question.

Comment: I meant that ellipsis is the process when a verb is omitted. For eg- **She is smart and he is handsome** and **She is smart and he handsome**. In the latter sentence, a verb is omitted and hence ellipsis has been applied. But in **Hence, it is proved** and **Hence, proved**, in the latter along with the verb **is**, the subject **it** is also omitted. So I meant does in ellipsis subject may also get omitted?

Comment: @Anubhav Singh: Where are you getting this narrow definition of 'ellipsis'?

Comment: **Greater the velocity, greater is the distance covered** and **Greater is the velocity, greater is the distance covered** is another example of ellipsis?

Comment: Idiomatic would be "*The* greater the velocity, the greater the distance covered". Yes, we could consider that as ellipsis of the verb "is". But if you intend to answer my question about your narrow definition of ellipsis with that example, then the question remains unanswered.